# Compilation error while using librsvg

Tags: c++, c, linux, svg, librsvg

I am using `librsvg` in my C files to rasterize SVG, but as soon as I include `rsvg.h`, I start to get the following error:

> /usr/include/librsvg-2.0/librsvg/rsvg.h:29:25: fatal error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory

1. Does anyone know why it is happenning and how to get rid of it? I tried including the path of glib headers but then it again starts to report other missing headers.
2. Is there any other open source library which I can use for rasterizing the SVG in C/C++?

Comment: Can you post your `g++` command line?

Comment: I used gcc renderSVG.cc -I/usr/include/librsvg-2.0/librsvg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `pkg-config` to get the proper flags to add, like this:

```
g++ -c -o renderSVG.o renderSVG.cc $(pkg-config --cflags librsvg-2.0)
g++ -o renderSVG renderSVG.o $(pkg-config --libs librsvg-2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including `glib`:

```
gcc renderSVG.cc -I/usr/include/librsvg-2.0/librsvg/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0
```

Comment: As i mentioned in question, I have tried this, but get another error: gcc renderSVG.cc -I/usr/include/librsvg-2.0/librsvg/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0/
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/librsvg-2.0/librsvg/rsvg.h:29,
                 from renderSVG.cc:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:34:24: fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I found the solution:

Correct command line is:

gcc pkg-config --cflags --libs librsvg-2.0 renderSVG.cc

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using autotools on Ubuntu Natty.
I have added in configure.ac

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBRSVG, librsvg-2.0 >= 2.0,
            [],
            [AC_MSG_FAILURE([librsvg not found])]
            )
```

and in Makefile.am

```
myexe_CFLAGS=@LIBRSVG_CFLAGS@ 
myexe_LDFLAGS=@LIBRSVG_LIBS@
```